# How to convert grayscale image to binary image in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, image-processing

Excuse me, I am doing my final paper, I try to convert image from RGB to grayscale, and from grayscale to binary, I have some code, but I don't know how to convert from grayscale to binary, hopefully, you could help me,

I use swift language in Xcode, I try to translate language form java, but I failed

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var openCVVersionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var myimageview: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageblack: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Invoke functions in OpenCVWrapper class from swift
    //openCVVersionLabel.text = OpenCVWrapper.openCVVersionString()
}

@IBAction func chooseimage(_ sender: Any) {
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self

    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary

    image.allowsEditing = true

    self.present(image, animated: true) {
        //After it is complete
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        myimageview.image = image
    }
    else {
        //Error message
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func convertTOBlack(image :UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)
    let blackImage = ciImage?.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [kCIInputSaturationKey:0.0])
    return UIImage(ciImage: blackImage!)
}

@IBAction func extractimage(_ sender: Any) {

    imageblack.image = convertTOBlack(image: myimageview.image!)

    }
}
```

I except it can change from RGB image to grayscale image, and from grayscale image to binary image.

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that "binary" can mean a lot of things. The underlaying data may be in one of many formats. The most common would be JPEG and PGN. To use those:

```
let pngData: Data? = image.pngData()
let jpegData: Data? = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: quality)
```

Then the other very important is to get raw RGB or RGBA bitmap data. To do so you will need to redraw your image to a new context and extract data from that context. It is a little bit complicated but you can find some solutions on web. Maybe try [here](https://gist.github.com/jokester/948616a1b881451796d6) if this is what you are looking for.